# Wordpress: target=''_blank" not working when using ajax_page_loader plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using ajax page loader plugin in wordpress . in every post page i m using

```
<a id="a_link" rel="nofollow" title="Print This Page" target="_blank" href="http://myurl.com/temp/?page_id=444&print=1">
<img class="WP-PrintIcon" style="border: 0px;" title="Print This Page" alt="Print This Page" src="http://myurl.com/temp/wp-content/plugins/wp-print/images/print.gif">
</a>
<a id="a_link" rel="nofollow" title="Print This Page" target="_blank" href="http://myurl.com/temp/?page_id=444&print=1">Print This Page</a>
```

But failed to open new tab. i also write code of JS in ajax page loader plugin's script where content loaded.
to load this this script on ajax page loading.

```
jQuery('a').click(function (event) {

            var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            if(id == 'a_link'){ var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");
                jQuery('#supersized-loader').css('display','none');
                window.open(href);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the design of your selector a bit to prevent it handling all links:

```
jQuery('a[target!="_blank"]').click(function (event)
```

This should prevent the ajax page loader from running on links with the attribute `target="_blank"`. The code you added inside the loader is obsolete then.

And: You can use an id only **once**. In your example you are using `a_link` at least twice.

Answer (score 0):

how about this jquery?

```
jQuery(document).delegate('a[target=_blank]', 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```